# How to add data to UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How to add data to UITableView ?
I need array of data inserted in this view

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[table numberOfRowsInSection:20];
table.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement the [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) protocol.

Have a look at the [Populating the Table View With Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW5) section of the iOS Table View Programming Guide.

Just because copy/paste is so much fun, here is the important methods that you need:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [regions count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Number of rows is the number of time zones in the region for the specified section.
    Region *region = [regions objectAtIndex:section];
    return [region.timeZoneWrappers count];
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // The header for the section is the region name -- get this from the region at the section index.
    Region *region = [regions objectAtIndex:section];
    return [region name];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    Region *region = [regions objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    TimeZoneWrapper *timeZoneWrapper = [region.timeZoneWrappers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = timeZoneWrapper.localeName;
    return cell;
```