# NSIndexPath to UITableView from other class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview

I'm a little confused how to use IndexPath to add row into TableView.
In first i init:

```
    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; 

    //rows code here

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Now between this two i would like to add some row to my table View. I have an NSArray with NSStrings contains elements name.

So i try this:

```
[[self tableView] beginUpdates];
[[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)myNames withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[[self tableView] endUpdates];
```

Then I've read that I should first add this somehow to UITableViewDataSource. So i declared it wrong? I'm asking becouse i'd rather avoid unnecessary passing data.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4022844/1228534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of the table view - and most views in [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) - is that they reflect the state of the model.  So, yes, as you suggested, have your datasource maintain an array:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *array;
```

Make changes to the array:

```
[self.array addObject:@"New Object"];
```

Record what rows have changed...

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.array count]-1 inSection:0];
NSArray *myNames = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
```

Then let the table view know that the model is different using the code you posted...

```
[[self tableView] beginUpdates];
[[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:myNames withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
[[self tableView] endUpdates];
```

Comment: But what kind of data i should have in array to display rows?

Comment: That's totally up to you.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *), the table view asks the datasource to configure a table cell.  This is where the app sets up strings or images or whatever _represents_ the model and puts them into a table cell.  In the case of the example code above, the array is an array of strings, so the translation is pretty straight-forward:  cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 1):

<strike>AFAIK that's not a very good way to add data to a UITableView.</strike> I misunderstood what you were trying to do, in either case you need to setup your tableview's datasource like this:

```
tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds]; 

[tableView setDataSource:self];

[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Then you need to implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol (and probably UITableViewDelegate).  You will want to implement the following datasource methods:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [myNames count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier@"MyIdentifier"] autorelease];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[myNames objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    return cell;
}
```

You might want to read up on the Reuse Identifier, it's necessary to ensure that your tables scroll smoothly and don't take up too much memory.